# What are the advantages/disadvantages of the CRV 2WD over the 4WD

Tags: 4wd, crv, 2wd

I am planning to buy a used `(2002-2006) Honda CRV` here in Lebanon.

I have two options: the `4WD` and the `2WD` (which have a lower cost than the `4WD`)

Please can you tell me what are the advantages/disadvantage of each one? and advice me to the better please.

Comment: Jad, welcome to the site. Unfortunately this question sounds like you want shopping advice, which is off-topic for the site.

Comment: @Zaid I think the question about pros and cons concerning 2WD and 4WD is an honest qeustion. I can't believe this isn't asked earlier though.

Comment: OP please note the difference between AWD and 4WD. 4WD or 4x4 is when all the wheels are kind of locked together, like when you climb the mountains in a Jeep. AWD is where all the wheels get power, but aren't necessarily linked together.

Comment: Dear All, I know the principles of 2WD/4WD but I am asking the persons that have a **HONDA CRV** 2WD a 4WD, what are their opinion about their car, eg: for the 2WD owners: is the car good or it is not enought good in mountains etc...

Comment: Depends on your climate and usage. You probably know better than us whether you need AWD where you live. A 2WD CRV will handle like most front wheel drive Hondas in the snow and rain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2WD get better gas mileage
4WD handles better in slippery situations - heavy rain, snow

If your someplace that regularly gets snow, go with the 4WD model.

I believe the CRV has AWD, not 4WD.

Answer (score 2):

A car with the possbility of 4WD next to 2WD will certainly be heavier, resulting in higher taxes, higher fuel consumption etc. 4WD itself is also more fuel consuming. On the other hand, you'll have better driveability, especially in bad weather or in the mountains, or when driving through mud/sand/grass etc.

But it's also another thing in your car that can break. Sounds weird, but what you don't have can't get broken. For example, the Mitsubishi Outlander 2004 was also available in 2WD only version, and in 4WD.(where you could switch between 2WD and 4WD) I have two familymembers, one had the 2WD, the other had the 4WD. The 4WD was designed after the 2WD, but it wasn't properly rebuild for that. For example, it had the same clutch. This among other things formed a problem. It was prone to failure because it wasn't designed to cope with the load of 4WD. The clutch always broke when applying a fair load in 4WD modus. I'd recommend you to google for these kind of stories for the Honda CRV.